# Are these null pointers, or are they pointers to address 0?

Tags: c++, c, null, language-lawyer, nullptr

If I write

```
int zero = 0;

void *p1 = (void *)0;
void *p2 = (void *)(int)0;
void *p3 = (void *)(0 /*no-op, but does it affect the next zero?*/, 0);

void *p4 = (void *)zero;    // For reference, this is a pointer to address zero
void *p5 = 0;               // For reference, this is a null pointer
void *p6 = NULL;            // For reference, this is a null pointer
void *p7 = nullptr;         // For reference, this is a null pointer (C++11)

static const int static_zero_1 = 0;       // Is this a literal zero when used?
static const int static_zero_2 = 1 - 1;   // No "literals 0" per se... is it?
void *p8 = (void *)static_zero_1;   // I have seen weird substitution rules...
void *p9 = (void *)static_zero_2;   // do they apply for NULL too?
```

which of `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` (**edit:** I added `p8` and `p9`) would be *null pointers* (i.e. `== NULL`, may or may not be address zero), and which of them would be pointers with the address zero (may or may not be `== NULL`)?

If the answer is different in C and C++, what is it in each of them?

Comment: Isn't a null pointer defined by "it points to address 0"?

Comment: p4 is also nullptr. Possibly you meant void *p4 = &zero;

Comment: The integer literal value `0` is, implicitly or explicitly converted to `void *`, is considered a `NULL` pointer. So p1, p2, p3, p5, p6 and p7 are all `NULL`.

Comment: @leemes: No, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759875/541686).

Comment: @Andrew: I meant to write what I wrote -- are you sure that's also nullptr? My understanding was that it's not, because it's not using a literal 0.

Comment: @Andrew Don't try to second guess Mehrdad - he's smarter than that.

Comment: @H2CO3: lol thanks. Could you explain why `p2` and `p3` are both null? Is `(int)0` considered a "literal" zero, so that it becomes a null pointer? And same with `(0, 0)`?

Comment: So according to your link, I'd guess `p1`, `p5`, `p6`, `p7` are null pointers, while `p2`, `p3`, `p4` are pointers with address 0 (because they are *expressions* but not *literal constants* with a value of 0, if I understand the linked answer correctly)

Comment: @Mehrdad *As far as I know,* `(void *)(int)0` is the literal `0`, explicitly converted to `int` then to `void *`. What about `(0, 0)`? Well, as I am starring at it for a longer time, it may not actually be the literal. It's an expression which evaluates to 0. I have to think twice before deciding which one it is...

Comment: @leemes: That was my guess too, but I wasn't sure -- in fact, let me throw in another example just to make it clearer why it's confusing me what's considered a constant and what's considered an expression!

Comment: BTW, how come you got no upvotes so far? Take my one.

Comment: @H2CO3: Lol thanks again. Yeah it's confusing to me, because I don't understand what's considered a literal and what's a (constant?) expression in C, if that differs in any way from C++, and how the language treats those in terms of being null. I through in a couple more examples to show what I mean -- it's really confusing me how the language treats each of them.

Comment: @Mehrdad In C, AFAIK it must be a literal, whereas in C++, apparently a [constant expression is enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016861/null-pointer-in-c-and-c), but I might be wrong regarding the first part.

Comment: @H2CO3: Interesting... I'm not sure how that would affect the static const examples, but that would mean `p2` or `p3` might be different in C and C++?

Comment: @Mehrdad No, I meant that `0` and `(0, 0)` would differ since the latter is not a literal. Fortunately, I was wrong and it is not the case - see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p1` and `p2` are null pointers; `p3` is implementation defined,
and may be something else.  (A comma operator cannot be part of
a constant expression.  And the mapping of a non-constant
integral value 0 to a pointer is implementation defined.)  C is
identical to C++ here.

`p8` and `p9` are both null pointers in C++, but not in C.

With regards to your comment on `static_zero_2`, there is no
requirement in either language that a literal zero be present,
anywhere.  g++ defines `NULL` as the compiler built-in `__null`,
for example, and you can use `(1 - 1)`, or `'\0'`, or any other
constant expression evaluating to 0.

Comment: I don't understand why `p3` is implementation defined. Where does the Standard say that a comma operator cannot be part of a constant expression?

Comment: @AndyProwl in 6.6 "constant expressions", p3 "*Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call,
or comma operators, ...*"

Comment: @JensGustedt: That's C, I'm talking about C++11

Comment: @AndyProwl, ah, you didn't say that, in C++11 you'd have to look for yourself, but chances are that this is similar.

Comment: But seeing that para 6.6 p 3 it is in the "constraints" section so actually this is not implementation defined. In C at least, this isn't a constant expression.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Sorry for not specifying that, in fact the question was implicitly for James, who wrote something along the same lines as a comment to my answer - and my answer deals explicitly with C++11. Moreover, the first sentence of this answer seems to target both C and C++

Comment: @AndyProwl The fact remains that the expression must be a conditional-expression, which doesn't allow the comma operator.  And that it doesn't work with any of the compilers I have access to, at least not in C++11 conformant mode.  _If_ this is something that was added to C++11, neither g++ nor MSVC support it yet.

Comment: @JamesKanze: In the comment to my answer I linked a live example proving the contrary. And I still don't see why `The fact remains that the expression must be a conditional-expression` implies that a comma operator cannot be used. That might be true in C, but it's not obvious at all in C++11 (see comments to my answer)

Comment: @AndyProwl I think you've convinced me with regards to C++11.  It's a newly added feature, however, which, as far as I can see, most compilers don't support yet.

Comment: @AndyProwl Question: is it a new feature in C++11, or is it simply something that got overlooked when the text was reworded?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Unfortunately I am not experienced enough to tell. For me, C++ is mostly C++11. I am admittedly ignorant about C, and I've never read the C++03 Standard. However, when I read the C++11 specification, I can't figure out where the comma operator would be forbidden explicitly or implicitly

Comment: @Andy Prowl - sounds like asking about the comma operator in that context is worth doing...

Comment: @AndyProwl It's hard to say.  As long as I've known C++ (and C before that), the comma operator has been forbidden in a constant expression.  On the other hand, I can't really see what problems it would create (unlike e.g. assignment).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I will try to do some research and if I will fail to figure it out I will eventually ask a specific question on SO

Comment: @AndyProwl The best place to ask would be in the newsgroups (comp.std.c++).  But I've not seen any activity there for awhile.  (All of the moderators are probably at the standards meeting in Bristol at the moment.)

Comment: +1 accepting this one because it pointed out the comma issue. All the answers were great though.

Answer (score 9):

And to make Andy's answer complete with C:

[From the C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object
>   type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void
>   and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.
>
> 3 An **integer constant expression with the value `0`**, or such an expression cast to type
>   `void *`, is called a **null pointer constant**.
>   55) If a null pointer constant is converted to a
>   pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal
>   to a pointer to any object or function.

So any **integer constant expression** which evaluates to `0` is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a `NULL` pointer. Effectively in your example, all pointers through except `p4`, `p8` and `p9` are null pointers. `p4`, `p8` and `p9` need not be null pointers since their initialization is not a constant expression because it contains variables (even if `const` qualified).

[Here's another answer about `NULL` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016861/null-pointer-in-c-and-c/7016898#7016898), for the record.

Comment: +1 *An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type `void *`*... ah, I guess that means they're *all* going to be null pointers in C (aside from `p4`), huh?

Comment: Now the hilarious thing is, if I said `const int zero = 0`, `p4` would still be address zero. But if I said `static const int zero = 0`, then it'd become a null pointer, right?! o_O

Comment: @Mehrdad Right, it's worth looking at section 6.6 of the Standard, I've just found it! Indeed, there's a reference to `static` in there (however, that's within the context of the addressof operator, which is slightly different).

Comment: In C, `p8` and `p9` aren't forced to be null pointers either. This comes from the fact that the term "integer constant expression" has a very specific definition in C, that excludes e.g `const` qualified variables as they are used for the initialization of `p8` and `p9`.

Comment: @Mehrdad No.  The static makes no difference.

Comment: @JensGustedt I didn't notice the edit on the question, my answer holds for pointers `p1...p7`, I'll update it with the correction, thanks!

Comment: So does this mean that the `NULL` macro has to expand to 0?  Since section 7.17 states that `NULL` expands to an "implementation-defined null pointer constant", 2 could be a perfectly valid null pointer.

Comment: @rm5248 Yes, `p2` is a null pointer, and the `NULL` macro has to either expand to an integer constant expression evaluating to 0. I'm not sure if it's permitted by the standard to expand to an internal compiler magic keyword, for example `__null` (that's what the standard library on OS X does recently).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Ah... I thought `static` had to be there for it to be a constant expression, but evidently not, thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad It's the reverse.  If this is at namespace scope, then `const` implies `static` as the default.

Answer (score 8):

> which of `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` would be null pointers?

In C++11, all of them. Per paragraph 4.10/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
>   zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [...]

Therefore, according to the terminology of the Standard, everything which is a *constant* (integral) expression and evaluates to `0` is a **null pointer constant** (not a *null pointer*, yet). The only one which is not a constant expression that evaluates to `0` or a prvalue of type `nullptr_t` in your example is `zero`, because it is not a constant expression.

The paragraph continues:

> A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the
>   result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or
>   function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a *null pointer conversion*. Two null pointer values of the
>   same type shall compare equal.

So in your example all the pointers except `p4` are *null pointer values* and compare equal among themselves.

Comment: Wow, so in C++11 it's really easy! +1 thanks, that answers at least part of the question.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Right, I am not a C guy so I'll leave the other part to someone with more experience ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl I did it - and I left out the C++ part because I'm not a C++ guy :D

Comment: @H2CO3: Oh, right, of course - I failed to see that you were quoting the C99 Standard ;) Well done

Comment: `p3` is _not_ a null pointer constant, since it is not a constant expression.  The wording in C++11 is more complex, but it is clear that constant expressions are "conditional-expression" meeting all of the other criteria.  A "conditional-expression" cannot contain a comma operator (or any assignment operator).

Comment: And of course, in C, neither `p8` nor `p9` are null pointers.  This is one place where C and C++ differ.

Comment: @AndyProwl I don't know.  Probably a bug in the compiler.  The standard is quite clear: "constant-expresssion: conditional-expression", so no comma operators or assignment operators are allowed.

Comment: @AndyProwl And g++ complains about `int arr[ (0, 42) ];`, at least when invoked with `-std=c++11 -pedantic`.  It's just a warning, but a warning is a diagnostic in the sense of the standard (according to the g++ documentation).

Comment: @AndyProwl MSVC rejects `int arr[ (0, 42) ]'` as well (with `-Za`, at least).  With an error, not just a warning.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't understand why a *conditional-expression* could not contain the comma operator, could you please explain?

Comment: @JamesKanze: If I follow the grammar, *conditional-expression* can be a *logical-or-expression*, which can be a *logical-and-expression*, which can be a *inclusive-or-expression*, which [...] can be a *unary-expression*, which can be a *postfix-expression*, which can be a *primary-expression*, which can be an *expression*, which can be an *expression , assignment-expression*. And while § 5.19 does specifically forbid assignments, it says nothing about the conditional operator.

Comment: @AndyProwl A primary-expression cannot be an expression.

Comment: @JamesKanze: According to A.4 a `primary-expression` can be an `( expression )`

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes.  A `primary-expression` can contain an `expression`.  But looking further, it may be that this something that was added to C++11 (it is expressedly forbidden in C++03 and C); if so, none of the compilers I have access to (g++ 4.7.2 and MSVC 11) support it yet.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The link I posted in a previous comment is using g++4.7.2 with the `std=c++11` flag

Comment: The code you posted in a previous comment causes a diagnostic with `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic`.  In other words, g++ considers it contrary to the standard, but supports it as an extension.  Other compilers, like MSVC, reject it out of hand.

Comment: @JamesKanze: What does the diagnostic say? I am using it here on my PC and I do not see any diagnostic apart from "unused variable"

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes.  The warning is on a different line.  Since I was looking for it (and already had an error from MSVC), I just reacted when I saw diagnostic output, without reading it too carefully.  And there's no diagnostic for `-std=c++03`, either, where it is clearly forbidden.  (C++03 simply copies the definition from C.)