# Is the comma operator allowed in a constant-expression in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, comma-operator, constant-expression

In the process of answering [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563114/are-these-null-pointers-or-are-they-pointers-to-address-0/16564608?noredirect=1#comment23807331_16564608) for C++11, I realized that in C++03 (as well as in C) the use of the comma operator is explicitly forbidden in a *constant-expression*.

Paragraph 5.19/1 of the C++03 Standard on constant expressions says:

> [...] In particular, except in sizeof expressions, functions, class objects, pointers, or
>   references shall not be used, and assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or **comma operators shall
>   not be used**.

In C++11, however, that last part mentioning the comma operator seems to be vanished. And while paragraph 5.19/2 of the C++11 Standard clearly specifies that assignment, increment, decrement, and non-`constexpr` function call expressions shall not appear as sub-expressions of a *constant-expression*, the usage of the comma operator does not seem to be forbidden anymore.

For instance, the following program compiles fine on GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.3 with `std=c++11` (apart from compiler warnings saying the comma operator has no effect and the `x` and `arr` variables are unused):

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int x = (0, 42);
    int arr[(0, 42)];
}
```

However, it must be said that even the following program compiles fine with the `-std=c++03` option (both on Clang and GCC), which is clearly *not* correct, given the above quote from the C++03 Standard:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[(0, 42)];
}
```

**QUESTION:**

Is there a difference between C++03 and C++11 as to whether or not the comma operator is allowed in a constant expression, or am I missing something?

As a bonus (non-constructive) question, I would be interested in knowing why the comma operator cannot be used in a constant expression in C++03.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Yes, I believe this is a change between C++03 and C++11. I believe it was done for roughly the reason to which you allude -- that there's no particularly good reason a comma operator can't be part of a constant expression.
2. I believe the rule in C++03 originated from the rule in C (C90, §6.4):

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within the operand of a **sizeof** operator.

As to why the comma operator was prohibited in constant expressions in C, I can only speculate. My immediate guess would be to assure that a definition like:

```
int x[5, 2];
```

...would be rejected. If it were allowed, it could lead the programmer to the mistaken belief that he'd defined a 5x2 element array (for a total of 10 elements), when (if a comma operator were allowed there) he'd really defined `x` with only 2 elements (and the `5` was effectively ignored completely).

As to why the C++ committee considered this a more acceptable risk than the C committee, I'd guess it comes down to a fairly simple situation: C provides nearly no alternative, so arrays are used quite a bit. C++, on the other hand, provides both `std::array` and `std::vector`, leaving extremely few situations in which there's much reason to use a "raw" array, so the problem is a lot less likely to arise.

Answer (score 5):

> However, it must be said that even the following program compiles fine with the -std=c++03 option (both on Clang and GCC), which is clearly not correct, given the above quote from the C++03 Standard

Not so fast. You need to also use `-pedantic` (or `-pedantic-errors`) to get Clang and GCC to strictly enforce the C++03 rules. With that, GCC trunk says:

```
<stdin>:1:16: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
```

and Clang trunk says:

```
<stdin>:1:19: error: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Werror,-Wvla-extension]
void f() { int arr[(0, 42)]; }
                  ^
```

As you note, this code is valid C++11. However, *top-level* commas are still not valid in C++11, because a *constant-expression* in the C++11 grammar is a kind of *conditional-expression* (where a top-level comma is not permitted). Thus:

```
int arr[0, 42];
```

is still ill-formed.