# Why is `pLQ->tail` a null pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, queue

I am working on an a queue and keep running into problems with enqueuing. Here is what I believe to be the relevant code:

```
typedef struct Qnode QNODE;
struct Qnode
{
  int length;
  QNODE* next;
  QNODE* prev;
};

typedef struct lqueue lQUEUE;
struct lqueue
{
   QNODE *head;
   QNODE *tail;
};

lQueue lqueue_init_default(void)
{
lQUEUE* pQ = NULL;
pQ = (lQUEUE*)malloc(sizeof(lQUEUE));
if (pQ != NULL)
{
    pQ->head = NULL;
    pQ->tail = NULL;
}
pQ->head = pQ->tail;
return pQ;
}

Status lqueue_henqueue(lQueue* hLQ, int lc)
{
lQUEUE* pLQ = (lQUEUE*)hLQ;
QNODE* new = (QNODE*)malloc(sizeof(QNODE));
if (new == NULL)
{
    printf("Couldn't allocate space.\n");
    return FAILURE;
}
new->length = lc;
new->next = pLQ->tail->next;

pLQ->tail = new;
return SUCCESS;
}
```

Whenever I try to run the program, I get this error during run time:
Exception thrown: read access violation.
`pLQ->tail` was nullptr.
Why is it a null pointer? Does it have to do with the Initialization function?
Here is how it is called:

```
int cl = 0;//Individual car length
lQueue hLQ = lqueue_init_default();//Handle to the left queue
printf("Enter the length of the lcar:\n");
            scanf("%d", &cl);
            lqueue_henqueue(hLQ, cl);
```

Comment: You'll have to show how `lqueue_henqueue` is called

Comment: `lQueue lqueue_init_default(void)` did you forget a `*` on the return type?

Comment: No, because when I do that, I get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

*Your code is highly prone to [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)... Look at this `if` statement:*

```
if (pQ != NULL)
{
    pQ->head = NULL; // This pointer is now 'NULL'
    pQ->tail = NULL; // This is also 'NULL'
}
```

*Which **should** be **this***...

```
if (pQ != NULL)
{
    pQ->head = (QNODE*)calloc(1, sizeof(lQUEUE)); // This is proper pointer initialization...
    pQ->tail = (QNODE*)calloc(1, sizeof(lQUEUE));
}
```

**And this:**

```
lQueue lqueue_init_default(void)
```

**should be this:**

```
lQueue * lqueue_init_default(void) // Since you are returning a pointer...
```

You will see that the code works fine because there is no *undefined behavior*...

> Note that you can [**never access an object that is assigned to NULL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061203/attempting-to-access-a-null-pointer*)... (*Only if you **don't want your program to behave undefined***...) So, this:
>
> ```
> pQ->tail = NULL;
> ```
>
> is **not safe** in the very least... Structural pointers being assigned to *`NULL`* are usually only seen when being *destroyed*... *An example is given below...*

---

**Also, *unrelated*, but have a *destructor* for the structure and call it when you don't need the structure anymore, or it will *leak the memory afterwards*...**

```
void destroy_lqueue(struct lqueue ** queue)
{
    if (queue != NULL)
        queue = NULL;
    free(queue);
}
```