# Understanding summation logic

Tags: c

Here is the [summation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365522/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-two-numbers-without-using-the-operator/366247#366247) logic which performs addition without using `+` operator as below,

```
int add(int a, int b) {
   const char *c=0;
   return &(&c[a])[b];
}
```

Can anyone make me understand how `return` statement boils to addition of `a` & `b`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just remember that since `a[b]` is the same as `*(a + b)`, there's an implicit add being done whenever you index an array. That means that `&a[b]` is `a + b` since the address-of and dereference operators cancel out.

Then, with `c` set to `0`, we can substitute:

```
&(&c[a])[b] = &(&*(0 + a))[b] = &(a)[b] = &a[b] = &*(a + b) = a + b
```

I'm not sure this is well-defined and portable, but I imagine it'll work on most "typical" systems.

Comment: I think it is not portable. What if internal representation NULL pointer is not `0`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016861/null-pointer-in-c-and-c this may answer your question ;)

Comment: @Theolodis I'm not sure how that is relevant? I was wondering about systems where `NULL` is not numeric address value `0x00000000`, so compiler might replace `const char *c=0;` with `const char *c= (void*)0x0BADC0DE;`  during compilation.

Comment: @user694733 In C++, the null pointer is defined by the ISO specification (§4.10/1) as `A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type **that evaluates to zero**.` If you would read what I gave you... ;D

Comment: @Theolodis I did, but that is not what I meant. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759875/694733

Comment: @user694733 if it evaluates to 0 it doesn't matter what its internal representation is.

Comment: @Theolodis But computation happens at runtime so `c[a]`, would become `0x0BADC0DE + a`, not `0 + a`.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, it is not as complex as you think, but for sure **nothing you should use** because it's kind of dirty ;)

`c` is a pointer to `NULL` or `0` and you take the offset `&0[a]`, which is exactly `a`, then you take the offset `[b]` from `&0[a]`, which is `0+a+b`.

And that's all the magic.

Answer (score 3):

This is just addition of pointer that leads to addition.

To understand it

```
 &c[a]  = c + a;
```

and

```
 &(&c[a])[b] = &c[a] + b = c + a + b;
```

When you take `&(&c[a])[b]`, it will give `c + a + b`. Since c is 0, it is `a+b`.

In fact to get summation of two integer without `+` operator, use bitwise operators and the logic that is used in full adder circuit.