# Undefined variable when initialized in switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

The question itself begs an obvious answer. In any case, here's a snippet of my code...

```
    switch(cSet)...

    case 8:{ //Special Characters
        finalSet = special;
        char* charSet = new char[special.size() + 1];
        charSet[special.size()] = 0; //Append null terminator
        memcpy(charSet, special.c_str(), special.size());
        break;
    }

    case 9:{ //Alphnumeric and Special character
        finalSet = all;
        char* charSet = new char[all.size() + 1];
        charSet[all.size()] = 0; //Append null terminator
        memcpy(charSet, all.c_str(), all.size());
        break;
    }
    ...
```

Note that `finalSet` is of type `std::string`. I'm needing to save it as a character array. After this statement, I call `charSet` outside of the switch statement:

```
    for(int i = 0; charSet; i++)
         printf("%s", charSet[i]);
```

Now, it is obvious that switch statements are conditional, so a variable may not always be declared. So Visual Studio 2012 is throwing the error "`charSet` is undefined." The way I have my switch statement structured, though, `charSet` will always be defined, or the program will exit in the `default` case.

To remedy this issue, I attempted to declare `charSet` outside the scope of the switch statement. When I do this, however, for some reason the compiler throws a read access error.

I'm curious as to how I can fix this issue.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Error code when declaring outside of switch statement:

```
`Unhandled exception at 0x0F6616B3 (msvcr110d.dll) in cuda_comb.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000061.`
```

Comment: Please show the other error in detail.  You should be declaring the charSet outsize the switch statement, as you stated.

Comment: Sure, give me a moment...

Comment: You have two different `charSet` variables, declared in different scopes. Any value you assign to `charSet` is lost when execution reaches the `break` statement, and the name `charSet` is not visible outside the enclosing block. And you have a memory leak.

Comment: If using C++11, you can just use the `std::string`'s buffer as a modifiable character array to some extent.

Comment: Looks like the condition in your `for` loop is off, you probably want something like `for (char *it = charSet; *it; ++it) printf("%c", *it);`

Comment: You are accessing invalid memory.  You should be able to set a breakpoint in the debugger and see the offending line.  Usually, you have overrun a buffer.

Comment: Yes, I figured as much. Like @Kninnug pointed out, it was due to an error in my for loop.

Comment: Yup, `%s` should be `%c` in your `printf`

Comment: Sorry, it seems you noticed it but I'll say it just in case. You also don't have the correct stop condition in `for(int i = 0; charSet; i++)` try `for(int i = 0; charSet[i]; i++)`

Comment: How have you declared it? I mean, if you declared it just `char* charSet;` and you're not entering in a case that allocs some memory, you're reading an invalid memory position. Please, check my solution proposal in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you took it out did you try (before the switch):

```
char* charSet = 0;
```

and then in all the switch statements remove the `char *`, so

```
char* charSet = new char[all.size() + 1];
```

becomes:

```
charSet = new char[all.size() + 1];
```

then your code can even check (after the switch):

```
if (!charSet)
{
  // handle odd case
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `0` and not `NULL`?

Comment: @nonsensickle this is C++, not C

Comment: @Slava Well in that case wouldn't `std::nullptr` be more correct? You are setting an integer value to a pointer, it shouldn't be correct.

Comment: This is covered in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c - 0 works pre C++11 see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016861/null-pointer-in-c-and-c

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Hmm, you both got me there. It is a valid argument. Thanks, I learned something new today.

Answer (score 5):

1. You **have to** declare `charSet` outside the `switch`. When the variable is declared inside the switch/case it will run out of scope when the switch ends, even if the case that declares the variable is executed.
2. Your `for(int i = 0; charSet; i++)` loops as long as `charSet` isn't 0 and increments `i` every time. Because you don't change `charSet` inside the for it will always not be 0 so that eventually `charSet[i]` is out of bounds and gives you the read access error. Change it so that it loops until `i` is greater than the length of the buffer, or `charSet[i] == '0'` (the terminating-null). For example:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; charSet[i]; i++) 
       printf("%c", charSet[i]);
   ```
3. Also change the `%s` in the `printf` to `%c` as you're printing a `char`, not a `char *`. Although, as you're printing a null-terminated string anyway, you can avoid the `for` loop altogether:

   ```
   printf("%s", charSet);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You're defining `charSet` on every case block, although you allocated memory on the heap for this array, outside these blocks, `charSet` reference is undefined as the builder is showing.

Note that, by doing this, if you were not using `charSet` outside switch block, you will receive no error but you will be leaking memory.

I mean:

```
switch(cSet)...

case 8:{ //Special Characters
    finalSet = special;
    char* charSet = new char[special.size() + 1]; // <-- charSet definition
    charSet[special.size()] = 0; //Append null terminator
    memcpy(charSet, special.c_str(), special.size());
    break;
} // <-- charSet reference lost, Memory leak

case 9:{ //Alphnumeric and Special character
    finalSet = all;
    char* charSet = new char[all.size() + 1]; // charSet definition
    charSet[all.size()] = 0; //Append null terminator
    memcpy(charSet, all.c_str(), all.size());
    break;
} // <-- charSet reference lost, Memory leak

} // End of switch

    for(int i = 0; charSet; i++)
     printf("%s", charSet[i]); // <-- Error charSet is not defined
```

Correct solution for this is declaring charSet outside the switch statement so you won't lose the reference:

```
char* charSet = NULL;
switch(cSet)...

case 8:{ //Special Characters
    finalSet = special;
    charSet = new char[special.size() + 1];
    charSet[special.size()] = 0; //Append null terminator
    memcpy(charSet, special.c_str(), special.size());
    break;
}
...
}

if(charSet)
   printf("%s", charSet);
```

Note that, as you're printing an array with "%s", you can directly use `charSet`.

Comment: Umm, you too copied his error. `printf("%s", charSet[i]);` should be `printf("%c", charSet[i]);` shouldn't it? As well as you don't have a stop condition for the loop... Try `for(int i = 0; charSet[i]; i++)` instead.

Comment: @nonsensickle Don't worry, it was just a fast copy paste from original source code. After reviewing, I thought that, for code cleanliness, it should be better just to use a single `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your code looks like this:

```
 switch(cSet){    
        case 8:{ //Special Characters           
           char* charSet  = new char[special.size() + 1];
           //code
           break;
          }
         case 9:{ //Special Characters           
           char* charSet = new char[all.size() + 1];
           //code
           break;
           }
        //other cases
     }

   for(int i = 0; charSet; i++)
         printf("%s", charSet[i]);
```

In this case even though you define charset for each case, you restrict the scope of charset to each case where it's defined - which you already figured out and moved the pointer declaration outside the switch - like:

```
char* charSet;
switch(cSet){    
       //code
}
```

The error you are getting basically says you are reading from an invalid memory location. Which can happen if you don't assign the pointer to a dynamically allocated memory location. Even though you seem to allocate memory for charSet for all cases of the switch statement, don't forget you have a default case as well.

Hope it helps.