# Compile error 'nullptr' undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, nullptr

I'm trying to compile a source with Visual Studio 2008 Express, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error C2065: 'nullptr' undeclared identifier.
```

My code:

```
if (Data == nullptr) {
    show("Data is null");
    return 0;
}
```

I read on Google that I should upgrade to Visual Studio 2010, but I don't want to do this because of the IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2008. Can this be repaired or replaced?

Comment: `nullptr` is a newer language feature and it looks like your compiler just doesn't support it. The old was of doing this was to check against 0 but that's not quite as typesafe. Also you might want to read this http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/nullptr

Comment: You can only use `nullptr` in Visual Studio 2010 and newer, it is a C++11 feature.

Comment: What's the difference between intelisense in VS2008 and VS2010?

Comment: You can upgrade to VS2010, how/why would that impact your usage of Intellisense?

Comment: You know that VS2008 does not support `nullptr`. You know the solution is to use a newer compiler. And yet you want to somehow find a way to change the compiler without changing compiler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the compiler doesn't recognize the `nullptr` keyword. This is because `nullptr` was introduced in a later version of visual studio than the one you are using.

There's 2 ways you might go about getting this to work in an older version. One idea comes from Scott Meyers c++ book where he suggests creating a header with a class that emulates `nullptr` like this:

```
const // It is a const object...
class nullptr_t 
{
  public:
    template<class T>
    inline operator T*() const // convertible to any type of null non-member pointer...
    { return 0; }

    template<class C, class T>
    inline operator T C::*() const   // or any type of null member pointer...
    { return 0; }

  private:
    void operator&() const;  // Can't take address of nullptr

} nullptr = {};
```

This way you just need to conditionally include the file based on the version of msvc

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1600 //MSVC version <8
     #include "nullptr_emulation.h"
#endif
```

This has the advantage of using the same keyword and makes upgrading to a new compiler a fair bit easier (and please do upgrade if you can). If you now compile with a newer compiler then your custom code doesn't get used at all and you are only using the c++ language, I feel as though this is important going forward.

If you don't want to take that approach you could go with something that emulates the old C style approach (`#define NULL ((void *)0)`) where you make a macro for `NULL` like this:

```
#define NULL 0

if(data == NULL){
}
```

Note that this isn't quite the same as `NULL` as found in C, for more discussion on that see this question: [Why are NULL pointers defined differently in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016861/why-are-null-pointers-defined-differently-in-c-and-c)

The downsides to this is that you have to change the source code and it is not typesafe like `nullptr`. So use this with caution, it can introduce some subtle bugs if you aren't careful and it was these subtle bugs that motivated the development of `nullptr` in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

`nullptr` is part of C++11, in C++03 you simply use `0`:

```
if (!Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

When it's not recommended to edit sources, you can just give your c++ compiler appropriate define. For example, in CMakeLists.txt I've added line:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Dnullptr=0")
```

And everything worked well