# const char[] default function argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I have defined a type like this:

```
typedef char sType[256];
```

and a function, with default parameter:

```
void foo(const sType param = NULL);
```

MinGW (g++ 4.8.0) compiles it without errors.

Instead, Visual Studio 2015 (Tools 14.0) gives the following error:

```
error C2040: 'sType': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [256]'
```

I tried to cast `NULL` to `const char[]`, but this leads to:

```
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'int' to 'const char []'
```

Any hint? Thank you

Comment: try using `nullptr`, instead of `NULL` (also, update your old broken compiler to a modern one http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).

Comment: I get `error C2065: 'nullptr': undeclared identifier`. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433436/compile-error-nullptr-undeclared-identifier) (`nullptr` emulation) but I get other errors.

Comment: You're using an ancient, pre c++11 compiler, so that's no surprise.

Comment: VS2015 should be recent enough to know c++11 and nullptr.....

Comment: Seems like a MSVC bug. Does it work if you use `(char *)NULL` instead.  (BTW in case you were unaware, `const sType` in this context means `char * const` and not `const char *`)

Comment: Tried cast to `char *` or `const char *` but the error is still there ("'int' differs in level of indirection..."). However, it is related to something specific to my project because I tried starting a simple project from scratch and it worked. I wonder if I should cancel this thread...

Answer (score 0):

Cast `NULL` not to `const char[]` (or `sType`) but to `const char*`.  Function parameters undergo array-to-pointer decay in the [very declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function).

Comment: Tried cast to `char *` or `const char *` but the error is still there ("'int' differs in level of indirection..."). However, it is related to something specific to my project because I tried starting a simple project from scratch and it worked. I wonder if I should cancel this thread...